# Class wordplay with four methods

Tags: python, string, class

I have the following problem and two very important questions.
Write a class called Wordplay. It should have a field that holds a list of words. The user
of the class should pass the list of words they want to use to the class. There should be the
following methods:

- words_with_length(length) — returns a list of all the words of length length
- starts_with(s) — returns a list of all the words that start with s
- ends_with(s) — returns a list of all the words that end with s
- palindromes() — returns a list of all the palindromes in the list

First problem. After compiling my program the methods starts with and ends with return the same word.
Next problem. In this case i have created a list of three names. But what if i wanted to ask for a list size and iterate over it while asking to input a word. How can i implement that idea?

```
class Wordplay:

  def __init__(self):
    self.words_list=[]

  def words_with_lenght(self,lenght):
    for i in range(0,len(self.words_list)-1):
      if len(self.words_list[i])==lenght:
        return self.words_list[i]

  def starts_with_s(self,s):
    for i in range(0,len(self.words_list)-1):
      if s.startswith('s')==True:
        return self.words_list[i]

  def ends_with_s(self,s):
    for i in range(0,len(self.words_list)-1):
      if s.endswith('s')==True:
        return self.words_list[i]

  def palindromes(self):
    for i in range(0,len(self.words_list)-1):
      normal_word=self.words_list[i]
      reversed_word=normal_word[::-1]
      if reversed_word==normal_word:
        return reversed_word

verification=Wordplay()
verification.words_list=['sandro','abba','luis']
lenght=int(input('Digit size you want to compare\n'))
s='s'
print(verification.words_with_lenght(lenght))
print(verification.starts_with_s(s))
print(verification.ends_with_s(s))
print(verification.palindromes())
```

If i input for example size 4 i expect the result to be:
abba,luis  ;   sandro  ; luis    ; abba      and not-
abba; sandro ; sandro ; abba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `if s.startswith('s')==True:`, you've passed the string `"s"` into the function resulting in

```
if 's'.startswith('s')==True: 
#  ^^^
  return self.words_list[i]
```

This conditional is always true. You probably don't need a parameter here at all since the assignment asks you to [hard code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) `"s"`. You can use:

```
if self.words_list[i].startswith('s'): 
    return self.words_list[i]
```

Notice the above example uses a `return` as soon as a match is found. This is a problem. The loops in this program break early, returning from the function as soon as a single match is located. You may have intended to append each successful match to a list and return the resulting list or use the `yield` keyword to return a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) (but the caller would need to use `list()` if they want a persistent list from the generator). Using a list to build a result would look like:

```
result = []

for i in range(len(self.words_list)):
    if self.words_list[i].startswith('s'): 
        result.append(self.words_list[i])

return result
```

Another issue: the loops in this program don't iterate all the way through their respective lists. The `range()` function is inclusive of the start and exclusive of the end, so you likely intended `range(len(self.words_list))` instead of `range(0, len(self.words_list) - 1)`.

Beyond that, there are a number of design and style points I'd like to suggest:

- Use horizontal space between operators and use vertical whitespace around blocks.

  ```
  foo=bar.corge(a,b,c)
  if foo==baz:
    return quux
  ```

  is clearer as

  ```
  foo = bar.corge(a, b, c)

  if foo == baz:
      return quux
  ```
- Use 4 spaces to indent instead of 2, which makes it easier to quickly determine which code is in which block.
- Prefer `for element in my_list` instead of `for i in range(len(my_list))`. If you need the index, in most cases you can use `for i, elem in enumerate(my_list)`. Better yet, use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to perform filtering operations, which is most of this logic.
- There's no need to use `if condition == True`. `if condition` is sufficient. You can simplify confusing and inaccurate logic like:

  ```
  def palindromes(self):
    for i in range(0,len(self.words_list)-1):
      normal_word=self.words_list[i]
      reversed_word=normal_word[::-1]
      if reversed_word==normal_word:
        return reversed_word
  ```

  to, for example:

  ```
  def palindromes(self):
      return [word for word in self.words_list if word[::-1] == word]
  ```

  that is, avoid intermediate variables and indexes whenever possible.
- I realize you're probably tied down to the design, but this strikes me as a strange way to write a utility class. It'd be more flexible as static methods that operate on iterables. Typical usage might be like:

  ```
  from Wordplay import is_palindrome

  is_palindrome(some_iterable)
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  wordplay = Wordplay(some_iterable)
  wordplay.palindromes()
  ```

  My rationale is that this class is basically stateless, so it seems odd to impose state when none is needed. This is a bit subjective, but worth noting (if you've ever used the `math` or `random` modules, it's the same idea).

  The lack of parameter in the constructor is even weirder; the client of the class has to magically "know" somehow that `words_list` is the internal variable name they need to make an assignment to in order to populate class state. This variable name should be an implementation detail that the client has no idea about. Failing providing a parameter in the initialization function, there should be a setter for this field (or just skip internal state entirely).
- `ends_with_s(self, s)` is a silly function; it seems the designer is confused between wanting to write `ends_with(self, letter)` and `ends_with_s(self)` (the former is far preferable). What if you want a new letter? Do you need to write dozens of functions for each possible ending character `ends_with_a`, `ends_with_b`, `ends_with_c`, etc? I realize it's just a contrived assignment, but the class still exhibits poor design.
- Spelling error: `words_with_lenght` -> `words_with_length`.

---

Here's a general tip on how to build the skill at locating these problems: work in very small chunks and run your program often. It appears that these four functions were written all in one go without testing each function along the way to make sure it worked first. This is apparent because the same mistakes were repeated in all four functions.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm learning python with the help of the book 'A pratical introduction to Python'. I have 2 months of programing skills. Obviously i don't have (at least by todays standards) the skills to be less confusing or neither have i the skills to write code in a simpler way. I think that will come with years of practising but yes i write many lines when i could write one or two at the most.

Comment: You're doing fine. Simplicity will come with practice and I hope all of this came across as non-personal. Good luck with your code!

Comment: and i dont get the 'word for word'

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) or another tutorial on list comprehensions. It's advanced, so no need to use it if you're not comfortable with it--it's just shorthand for a loop that appends to a list, with an optional conditional that filters items out.

Answer (score 1):

`s.endswith('s')` compares your input string `s` ("s") with `"s"`. "s" ends in "s", so it always returns your first entry. Change it to `if self.words_list[i].startswith('s'):` (same for `endswith`).

I would recommend changing your for loops to iterate over the words themselves though:

```
def ends_with_s(self, s):
    for word in self.words_list:
        if word.endswith('s'):
            return word
```

Entering a list of values as you described:

```
amount = int(input("How many words? "))
words = [input("Word {}".format(i + 1)) for i in range(amount)]
```